# generate sourcemap from browserify and uglify

Tags: node.js, browserify, uglifyjs

I want to generate a min js with sourcemap using browserify and uglify.

I am using node and npm script.

When I run "npm run processjs", it gives me bundle.js and bundle.js.map. But when I open the app in chrome, chrome only show the code is from the file of "bundle.js", not from the file of origin js of each module.

```
"buildjs": "node node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js src/index.js -o src/bundle.js" ,
"uglifyjs": "node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs src/bundle.js -o src/bundle.js --source-map src/bundle.js.map -p relative",
"processjs": "npm run buildjs && npm run uglifyjs",
```

Is there anyway that the source map actually map to each module js, instead of the single bundle.js

Comment: if you want  it to map the modules rather than the bundle - check out the source map stuff in browserify - then the source map will point back to the original files : [browserify docs](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) I believe it is the debug flag that you want to generate that - I use it and it works in chrome

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is as part of the browserify part to include the `--debug` flag. From the docs:

> `--debug` `-d`  Enable source maps that allow you to debug your files
>                      separately.
>   rather than mapping in the uglify step which would map your bundle

Comment: Thx. I tried it works if NO uglify applied. Once uglify applied, chrome still not shown origin module files. So is it not possible to have source map point to origin module files while having the actual js script minified?

Comment: try looking the docs [here](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) - there are a few other source map flags that might help